# Java Client for Android - constat channel with server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, channel

I'm developing mobile application that makes your smartphone as controller for the game.
The communication between mobile client and server should be as quick as possible (mobile app is going to send basic commands in JSON format)
Server side is Google App Engine and I thought to use Channel API which works great with web browser clients but there is no official client in Java.

Could you recommend how to create persistent connection with server for quick communication ?
I found some GAE Channel API implementations for Android but it seems like it doesn't work ;/